# Password is not matched with pattern in Angular CLI

Tags: html, regex, angular, passwords

I have a problem with password validation, I am using a regex such as;

```
'(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'
```

and my ng-form field is;

```
password: ['', [Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'), Validators.required]]
```

also in HTML, I get input as;

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="******" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.password.errors">Invalid Password</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

where **f** is  function such as;

```
 get f() {
     return this.userForm.controls; 
 }
```

When I entered a password as: **Harun123**, I get invalid password error. Why this happens?

Comment: I also added ^ at the beginning of expression

Answer (score 0):

This question could be solved with a combination of these two answers:

So first of all, you would need a custom validator for checking the passwords, that could look like this

```
checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) { // here we have the 'passwords' group
let pass = group.controls.password.value;
let confirmPass = group.controls.confirmPass.value;

return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }     
}
```

and you would create a formgroup for your fields, instead of just two form controls, then mark that custom validator for your form group:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
password: ['', [Validators.required]],
confirmPassword: ['']
}, {validator: this.checkPasswords })
```

and then as mentioned in other answer, the `mat-error` only shows if a FormControl is invalid, so you need an error state matcher:

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | 
null): boolean {
const invalidCtrl = !!(control && control.invalid && control.parent.dirty);
const invalidParent = !!(control && control.parent && control.parent.invalid 
&& control.parent.dirty);

return (invalidCtrl || invalidParent);
 }
}
```

in the above you can tweak when to show error message. I would only show message when the password field is touched. Also I would like above, remove the required validator from the confirmPassword field, since the form is not valid anyway if passwords do not match.

Then in component, create a new `ErrorStateMatcher`:

```
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

Finally, the template would look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="New password" formControlName="password" 
required>
<mat-error *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'password')">
    Please enter your new password
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="Confirm password" 
formControlName="confirmPassword" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
<mat-error *ngIf="myForm.hasError('notSame')">
    Passwords do not match
</mat-error>  
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here's a demo for you with the above code: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhbuqn-s5lmtv?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts)